# How to implement Jax-RS Basic Authentication?

Tags: java, jax-rs, basic-authentication, request-headers, response-headers

How to implement JAX-RS basic authentication and authorization for each request? I am doing following steps.

1. accepting user name and password from `@HeaderParam`
2. decoding it
3. After authentication set the unique token in response header.
   up to this step it works fine.

But how can I validate the user for new request? For new request the `@HeaderParam("Authorization")` is null.

My code is

```
@GET
@Path("/login")
public Response login(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authString){
    String reponseHeader="";
    String reponseHeaderValue="";
    int errorCode=0;
    try{
        if(authString!=null){
            System.out.println("#########" + authString);
            String[] authParts = authString.split("\\s+");
            String authInfo = authParts[1];
            // Decode the data back to original string
            byte[] bytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(authInfo);
            String decodedAuth = new String(bytes);
            System.out.println(decodedAuth);
           String[] credentials = decodedAuth.split(":");
            UserAuthentication userAuthentication = getService(UserAuthentication.class);
            if(userAuthentication == null)
                throw new UserAuthenticationException("Unable to get UserAuthentication Service");
            String userName = credentials[0];
            String pwd =   credentials[1];
            LoginSession obj_Session = userAuthentication.authenticateUser(userName,pwd);
            sessionCount = sessionCount + 1;
            String strSessionKey = userName  + "_" + sessionCount + "";
            reponseHeaderValue="Basic "+strSessionKey;
            reponseHeader="Authorization:";
            errorCode=200;
        }else{
            reponseHeaderValue="User Visible Realm";
            reponseHeader="WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=";
            errorCode=401;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.ok().header(reponseHeader, reponseHeaderValue).status(errorCode).build();
}
```

This is how I authenticate the user. Once it gets authenticated for next request i.e.

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public String getProjectList(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authString){
    System.out.println("##############"+authString);
    System.out.println("##############");
    return authString;
}
```

But `@HeaderParam("Authorization")` is null that's why I can't authorize the user.

Comment: Without code details its hard to say, but I would assume the header isn't set. In this case you should reply with 401, so the client knows it needs to set the header.

Comment: @CannedMoose I aunticated the user but my problem is, How to  authenticate the user for different request. I mean once user get authenticated for next request I want the same token which is I have added in response header.

Comment: HTTP basic authentication is pretty straight forward. The next request again needs the basic authentication information again. Or you somehow pass your token along and handle that manually. But without code its hard to say what is actually done

Comment: @CannedMoose now I added my code please help me or suggest me site for complete example.

Comment: You can either send the token in response body of the login method and make the user send the token in each request or you can store it in a cookie.

Comment: @OnkarG I think you are trying to do more then the basic auth can do. The client needs to read the token from your response and set it in its next request **manually**. There is no automatic way to do that.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks

Comment: @CannedMoose Thanks